# Where should my (angular) data-manipulation logic go when polling for data

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on my first large(ish)-scale Angular project.

I have an angular service which polls for and returns JSON data from a web-service every 5 seconds.

This data is structured somewhat like this:

```
- Top Level
  - Category
    - Item
      - details
      - ... more details
    - Item
      - ...
  - Category 2
    - Item
      ...
```

When polling, the categories will generally remain constant, but items will be added on most hits to the webservice.

In many cases I will be displaying the "items" by their category, but other times I will be collecting ALL items and filtering them by their details.

What is the cleanest way to approach this kind of thing. I've considered a few approaches, but not sure what is the best.

- Using filters (`{{topLevel | allItems | filter:... }}`)
- Having a service expose different configurations of the data using different $scope variables.
- just putting the login in the Controller and exposing different data configurations to different scope variables

Any thoughts / advice / suggested resources would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When I've done similar things, I just modify the data within my controller. Generally I'll have a couple functions that format data in the desired ways. But I store them all within the same `$scope` variable.

```
$scope.data - {
    categories: {...},
    allItems: {...},
    byID: {...}
}
```

Then within my view any event can be used to switch the way that it's being organized. I assume something like this would work for you as well, just depends on how much data you have, & how often you're polling, etc.